# Button Display Android Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, togglebutton

I have added a toggleButton, but it is not showing up and I cannot figure out why.  I have completed the Android tutorial, and have looked back at the code, as well as many other sources.  The objective is to have the program pause when the button is ON.  At the moment, the button will not even show up on the user interface.  Any suggestions?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:onClick="pauseCounter" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

```
package com.evorlor.counter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent counter = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Counter.class);

        startActivity(counter);

    }

    public void pauseCounter(View view) {
        Intent pause = new Intent(this, Pause.class);
        startActivity(pause);
    }

    // @Override
    // public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    // getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    // return true;
    // }

}
```

---

```
package com.evorlor.counter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Pause extends Activity{

    public void onCreate(Bundle instPause) {
        super.onCreate(instPause);

        TextView tv = new TextView(this);

        tv.setTextSize(250);
        tv.setText("PAUSE");
        setContentView(tv);

    }
}
```

---

Here is my Counter class. It is messy. Sorry. This is as close as I have come so far.  Help would be very appreciated!  I have spent a lot of time on this measly button!  Thanks!

```
package com.evorlor.counter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class Counter extends Activity {

    private int count = 0;
    private int hiCount = 0;
    private boolean capCount = false;

    public void onCreate(Bundle instCounter) {
        super.onCreate(instCounter);

        TextView tv = new TextView(this);

        tv.setTextSize(250);
        if (count < 10000 && capCount == false) {

            tv.setText(Integer.toString(count));
        } else {
            capCount = true;
            if (count >= 10000) {
                hiCount += 10;
                count -= 10000;
            }
            if (hiCount < 100) {

                tv.setText(hiCount + "k+" + count);
            } else {
                tv.setText("Over\n100k");
            }
        }
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        setContentView(tv);

        ToggleButton butPause = new ToggleButton(this);

        if (butPause == null) {
            Intent pause = new Intent(this, Pause.class);
            startActivity(pause);
        }

    }
    // public void pauseCounter(View view) {
    // Intent pause = new Intent(this, Pause.class);
    // startActivity(pause);
    // }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent counter = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Counter.class);

    startActivity(counter);

}
```

You are starting a new activity right away. thats not a good idea.
You are going to see what is in your Counter activity, not what is in your main activity, reason you don't see your toggle button. Comment out startActivity() just to check.

Comment: Thanks. I commented it out, and now my toggleButton is there...is it possible for me to have the toggle button there permanently?

Comment: Yes. Your toggle button will be there until you change activity. Just dont start a new activity in the onCreate() method. Use button events to do it.

Comment: I am looking at the button events info, and I do not see what I am doing wrong.  I want to have the button appear and remain while I am running Counter class.  I have tried moving the method to the end of that class, but then I am back to square one.  I tried moving it inside of the main method in Class, but no success there either...

Comment: Are you using the same layout for the Counter class? Add your counter class code.

Comment: Hmmm! Okay I see what you are trying to do. But with the code above you will only see the textview, because of the line setContentView(tv); I advise to make a xml layout with a the textview and the toggle button and on create you set view like this ; setcontentview(R.layout.counter_layout) just like your main activity. You can still do it programmatically as you are trying to do, but it is a more complicated.

Comment: Hmmm...I have deleted all of my SetContentView();'s and there is no change.  I am not really following you...if i put setContentView(R.layout.counter_layout), counter_layout comes up in red.

Comment: You have to created the layout just like activity_main.xml in the res/layout folder otherwise you will get an error. Copy activity_main.xml and change its name to conter_layout.xml and see.

Comment: Such a simple thing, yet I cannot get it :( I have spent enough hours on this futile task.  Thanks for your help.  Perhaps I will understand it tomorrow.